# Is there workaround for citus unsupported feature?

Tags: postgresql, citus

For the query:

```
SELECT
    cu.id id,
    cu.email email,
    SUM(case when(rt.type = 'credit' and ( re.type = 'account_refilling' OR re.type = 'site_publishing' OR re.type = 'tariff_buying' )) then rt.amount else 0 end ) transactions_sum
  FROM client_users cu
  JOIN referral_accounts ra ON ra.owner_id = cu.id
  LEFT JOIN referral_transactions rt ON rt.account_id = ra.id
  JOIN referral_events re ON re.id = rt.event_id
  GROUP BY cu.id, cu.email
  ORDER BY transactions_sum DESC
```

I got error:

```
ERROR:  cannot perform distributed planning on this query
DETAIL:  Cartesian products are currently unsupported
```

May I workaround this problem?

Answer (score 1):

That is strange, but error is disappeared when I distribute tables with same method and set equal shards count for tables in the query.

Comment: The reason this works is because you've probably now got _colocated_ shards, meaning the join can be satisfied locally on each node. If shards are different sizes or if join values are in different places, a repartition must occur, which is unsupported for this query (though not most `JOIN`s).